# Splitting a long INSERT ... SELECT into a loop

Tags: mysql, loops, bulkinsert

In MySQL, I need to perform a long `INSERT INTO t1 SELECT FROM t2`, and I don't want `t2` to remain write-locked too long.

My idea is to loop through `t2.id`, by repeatedly issuing queries like:

```
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT FROM t2 WHERE t2.id BETWEEN n0 AND n1
INSERT INTO t1 SELECT FROM t2 WHERE t2.id BETWEEN n1 AND n2
...
```

Two questions:

1. Is this a good idea, or is there a better solution?
2. Would you recommend creating a stored procedure with a LOOP in MySQL, or managing the loop via a script (e.g. bash)?

**Edit: as suggested in the comments, if dirty reads are acceptable (as in my case), `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` allows running the initial query with no locks.**

Comment: SELECT doesnt lock the table with `SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;` if you don`t mind dirty reads. Assuming InnoDb

Comment: @Mihai Thanks, sounds like a good solution in my case. I'll edit/post a solution as soon as I tested it.